# Why heroku app is serving my source files?

Tags: file, heroku, serving

Why my heroku app is serving **app** directory? This directory and it's files should not appear like you see in the picture. Should display only static directory.
I use rimraf npm package to remove sourcemaps (.map files) and when I use `serve -s build` command it works properly on localhost, it displays only the static directory. But when I deploy my files to heroku using heroku/nodejs buildpack it serves the files like in the picture. 
Important to note: I use just create react app and don't use any http server like express.js

@edit
Ok I know where is the problem. On localhost I use `serve -s build` and it serves just build directory. When I use npm start on localhost it serves `app` and `build` like on the heroku. Because I use `npm start` on heroku. But how to switch this command to serve? Tried to replace the start script with `"start": "serve -s build"` but it works only on localhost.

[image: google tools show source code]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this problem.
Right now I use npm start script which call `nodemon ./server.js` script which is just express server with get '/*' and send a index.html
No more `serve` or `react-scripts start` on production.